Proof of Weak Nullstellensatz
Following is corollary 1.1.13 of Liu’s algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves

(Weak Nullstellensatz). Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Then for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $k[T_1,…,T_n]$, there exists a unique point $(\alpha_1,… , \alpha_n)\in k^n$ such that $\mathfrak{m}$ is the ideal generated by $T_1−\alpha_1,…, T_n−\alpha_n$.
Proof By the preceding corollary (Noether normalization lemma), $k\to k[T_1, … , T_n]/\mathfrak{m}$ is an isomorphism. Let $\alpha_i \in k$ be the image of $T_i$ in $k[T_1,… , T_n]/\mathfrak{m}$. Then $T_i−\alpha_i \in \mathfrak{m}$. It follows that
$\mathfrak{m}$ contains the ideal $(T_1−\alpha_1, …, T_n−\alpha_n)$. Since the latter is maximal, there is
equality. The uniqueness of the $\alpha_i$ is immediate.

For the life of me I can’t see why $T_i-\alpha_i\in \mathfrak{m}$.

Let $\pi:k[T_1,T_2,\cdots,T_n]\longrightarrow k[T_1,T_2,\cdots,T_n]/\mathfrak{m}$ be the quotient map, it is $k$-linear. Then $\pi(T_i) = \alpha_i = \pi(\alpha_i)$, hence $\pi(T_i-\alpha_i) = 0$, that is, $T_i - \alpha_i  \in \mathrm{ker}(\pi) = \mathfrak{m}$.

Thank you so much for the answer. $\alpha_i=\pi (\alpha_i )$ in following sense $\pi (\alpha_i)=\alpha_i+\mathfrak{m}=\alpha_i (1+\mathfrak{m})=\alpha_i 1_{\text{Im}(\pi )}$. After posting this post, I figured out $$\alpha_i+\mathfrak{m} =\alpha_i (1+ \mathfrak{m}) = (T_i+ \mathfrak{m})(1+ \mathfrak{m})=T_i+ \mathfrak{m}$$ where first equality follows because $k[T_1,…,T_n]/\mathfrak{m}$ is $k$-algebra. Thus $T_i-\alpha_i\in \mathfrak{m}$.
